# Pywebsocket "rooms" or "topic" concept

Tags: mqtt, mod-pywebsocket

I'm experimenting with different ways to deliver data to some HTML5 pages through MQTT.

I've looked at **Node.js** together with **Socket.IO** and it seems like a nice solution since Socket.IO has a *"room"* concept which is easily translated to a MQTT *"topic"*.

I'm curious if **pywebsocket** have any such concept which would allow me to use the same websockethandler for multiple pages without sending the same data to all the pages.

I've had a look at the [pywebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) google code page together with [some examples](https://code.google.com/p/websocket-sample/) but I haven't been able to find any information that would allow this kind of behavior. If anyone has more information about this, I'd be very happy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I cannot give you any direct hint at translating the room concept of Socket.IO to MQTT, you might want to have a look at [Mosquitto.js](http://mosquitto.org/js/mosquitto-1.1.js) that allows you to easily establish MQTT connections via Websockets from a browser that behave very similarly like real Websockets. With this approach, every open page establishes a unique connection to the MQTT broker. Thus you can even subscribe to different topics depending on some conditions on the client-side.

A little example code:

```
  var mqttSocket = new Mosquitto();

  mqttSocket.onconnect = function(rc){
    console.log("Connection established");
  };

  mqttSocket.ondisconnect = function(rc){ 
    console.log("Connection terminated");
  };

  mqttSocket.onmessage = function(topic, payload, qos){
    console.log("Message received " + topic + ":" + payload);
  }

  mqttSocket.connect("ws://yourserver:8080"); 
  mqttSocket.subscribe('some/topic', 0);
```

As the native support for Websocket connections is not yet really implemented in any MQTT broker yet, there is a little pice of software required on the server side that bridges the Websocket connection to the MQTT broker.

The developer of Mosquitto.js recommends using a custom mod_websocket module for the Lighttpd webserver for this task. However, as an alternative you might want to try [WSS](https://github.com/stylpen/WSS) which translates any Websocket connection to an arbitrary other TCP port with minimal overhead

In respect to the example above, you would connect the mqttSocket to the adress and port where an instance of WSS is listening for incoming connections. WSS would then be configured to forward incoming connections to an MQTT broker of your choice.

Disclaimer: WSS has been written by a friend of mine to specifically bridge Mosquitto.js connections to an instance of the Mosquitto MQTT broker.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've been researching these things as well coming to the same conclusions. It seems that there is no "room" concept at the moment in pywebsocket. The experimental mosquitto versions wont really do what I'm hoping for since I don't want to run a separate http server. Thanks for your extensive answer though and hopefully this will aid others with the same problem as me.